# Rails : Unique address from array of active record addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to retrieve unique addresses which has got same latitude and longitude

```
> addresses
=> [#<Address id: 10, country: "IN", state: "KA", latitude: "12.971513803339702", longitude: "77.59443104418949", user_id: 11>, #<Address id: 9, country: "IN", state: "KA", latitude: "12.971513803339702", longitude: "77.59443104418949", user_id: 10>]
```

In this case I need any one of the ActiveRecord, as latitude and longitude are having similar values.

Comment: Try using [`group`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group).

Comment: addresses = Address.all.to_a
isn't it possible to get an uniq set of array by rejecting those records with matching latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the addresses by its latitude and longitude and then select the once with at least 2 addresses in a group:

```
addresses.
  group_by { |address| [address.latitude, address.longitude] }.
  select { |location, addresses| addresses.size >= 2 }.
  keys
```

Depending on your use case you might want to use [`distinct`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) (note that you lose `id` and `user_id` information):

```
Address.select(:country, :state, :latitude, :longitude).distinct
```

Comment: addresses = Address.all.to_a -> isn't it possible to get an uniq set of array by rejecting those records with matching latitude and longitude.

Comment: @ManjunathP : I updated my answer. It depends on what you want to do with that list. Can you please explain what you try to achieve with that list of unique addresses?